# Why does the update of this computed property fail in my Vue 3 app?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on an **audio player** with Vue 3 and the Napster API.

#### Project details

I have made the vinyl spin with the help of a CSS keyframes-based animation and the `isSpinning` computed property.

I want the vinyl to *stop spinning once the end of the current track is reached*, which is why `isSpinning` has this "formula":

```
isSpinning() {
  return this.isPlaying && !this.player.ended;
}
```

```js
const musicApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      player: new Audio(),
      trackCount: 0,
      tracks: [],
      muted: false,
      isPlaying: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getTracks() {
      try {
        const response = await axios
          .get(
            "https://api.napster.com/v2.1/tracks/top?apikey=ZTk2YjY4MjMtMDAzYy00MTg4LWE2MjYtZDIzNjJmMmM0YTdm"
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        this.tracks = response;
        this.tracks = response.data.tracks;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    nextTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount < this.tracks.length - 1) {
        this.trackCount++;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    prevTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount >= 1) {
        this.trackCount--;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    setPlayerSource() {
      this.player.src = this.tracks[this.trackCount].previewURL;
    },
    playPause() {
      if (this.player.paused) {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.player.play();
      } else {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.player.pause();
      }
    },
    toggleMute() {
      this.player.muted = !this.player.muted;
      this.muted = this.player.muted;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getTracks();
    this.setPlayerSource();
  },
  computed: {
    isSpinning() {
      return this.isPlaying && !this.player.ended;
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(musicApp).mount("#audioPlayer");
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2998ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #2998ff 0%, #5966eb 100%);
}

#audioPlayer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ca81;
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #00ca81 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume {
  color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.album {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.album-items {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/710/955/png-transparent-vinyl-record-artwork-phonograph-record-compact-disc-lp-record-disc-jockey-symbol-miscellaneous-classical-music-sound.png") center top transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover.spinning {
  webkit-animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.info h1 {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.info h2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.to-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.track {
  background-color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.controls {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ff0057;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.controls .navigate.navigate-play {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}

.navigate-play .fa-play {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.22.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="player-container">
  <div id="audioPlayer">
    <span class="volume" @click="toggleMute">
      <i v-show="!muted" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
      <i v-show="muted" class="fa fa-volume-off"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="album">
      <div class="album-items">
        <div class="cover" :class="{'spinning' : isSpinning}"></div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1>{{tracks[trackCount].name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{tracks[trackCount].artistName}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="to-bottom">
      <div class="track"></div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="navigate navigate-prev" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == 0}" @click="prevTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-play" @click="playPause">
          <i v-show="!isPlaying" class="fa fa-play"></i>
          <i v-show="isPlaying" class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-next" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == tracks.length - 1}" @click="nextTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### The problem

But, to my surprise, the app is unaware of the fact that the value of `this.player.ended` has changed (or is supposed to).

##### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Audio` object will not function in the same manner as normal JavaScript objects in Vue, as the internals that Vue uses to abstract away state change observation will not be maintained when the `Audio` object changes state. In other words, the thing that allows Vue to detect the `Audio` object switching from `ended === false` to `ended === true` won't work, preventing Vue from knowing that the component needs to be updated.

If you wish to observe a change in `ended` state, then you'll want to add a custom event listener to the object in your `created` hook to toggle the spinning state and simply remove the `ended` check:

```js
const musicApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      player: new Audio(),
      trackCount: 0,
      tracks: [],
      muted: false,
      isPlaying: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getTracks() {
      try {
        const response = await axios
          .get(
            "https://api.napster.com/v2.1/tracks/top?apikey=ZTk2YjY4MjMtMDAzYy00MTg4LWE2MjYtZDIzNjJmMmM0YTdm"
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        this.tracks = response;
        this.tracks = response.data.tracks;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    nextTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount < this.tracks.length - 1) {
        this.trackCount++;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    prevTrack() {
      if (this.trackCount >= 1) {
        this.trackCount--;
        this.setPlayerSource();
        this.playPause();
      }
    },
    setPlayerSource() {
      this.player.src = this.tracks[this.trackCount].previewURL;
    },
    playPause() {
      if (this.player.paused) {
        this.isPlaying = true;
        this.player.play();
      } else {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        this.player.pause();
      }
    },
    toggleMute() {
      this.player.muted = !this.player.muted;
      this.muted = this.player.muted;
    }
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getTracks();
    this.setPlayerSource();
    this.player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
      this.isPlaying = false;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    isSpinning() {
      return this.isPlaying;
    }
  }
};

Vue.createApp(musicApp).mount("#audioPlayer");
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2998ff;
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #2998ff 0%, #5966eb 100%);
}

#audioPlayer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #00ca81;
  background-image: linear-gradient(160deg, #00ca81 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume {
  color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.album {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.album-items {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: url("https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/710/955/png-transparent-vinyl-record-artwork-phonograph-record-compact-disc-lp-record-disc-jockey-symbol-miscellaneous-classical-music-sound.png") center top transparent;
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover.spinning {
  webkit-animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 6s linear infinite;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.85;
}

.info h1 {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.info h2 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.to-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.track {
  background-color: #ff0057;
  opacity: 0.9;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.controls {
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate {
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ff0057;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.controls .navigate.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #606060;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.controls .navigate.navigate-play {
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
}

.navigate-play .fa-play {
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.22.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="player-container">
  <div id="audioPlayer">
    <span class="volume" @click="toggleMute">
      <i v-show="!muted" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
      <i v-show="muted" class="fa fa-volume-off"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="album">
      <div class="album-items">
        <div class="cover" :class="{'spinning' : isSpinning}"></div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1>{{tracks[trackCount].name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{tracks[trackCount].artistName}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="to-bottom">
      <div class="track"></div>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="navigate navigate-prev" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == 0}" @click="prevTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-play" @click="playPause">
          <i v-show="!isPlaying" class="fa fa-play"></i>
          <i v-show="isPlaying" class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="navigate navigate-next" :class="{'disabled' : trackCount == tracks.length - 1}" @click="nextTrack">
          <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `ended` event instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement#events

```js
const audioElement = new Audio('car_horn.wav');
audioElement.addEventListener('ended', () => {
  this.isPlaying = false
})
```